# $\left[x \right]\times \left[x^{2}\right]= \left[x^{3}\right]$ then $x-[x]<\frac{1}{2700}$

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q:
If $x>30$,($[x]$: integer part of $x$)
$$\left[x \right]\times \left[x^{2}\right]= \left[x^{3}\right]$$
then show
$$x-[x]<\frac{1}{2700}$$

My study

I tried to transform it using the property $[x]\le x$, $x=n+\alpha(0 \le \alpha<1)$ but I have no idea how to transform the inequality and draw a conclusion. How could it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: $x>30$ and
$\left[x \right]\times \left[x^{2}\right]= \left[x^{3}\right]$
implies
$x-[x]<\frac{1}{2700}$.

Proof: Suppose not. Let $a=x-[x]$ and $n=[x]$. So we're saying $n\ge 30$ but $a\ge 1/2700$.

Note: $[x^2]=[(n+a)^2]=[n^2+2an+a^2] \geq [n^2+2an]=n^2+[2an]$.

Similarly $[x^3]\ge n^3+[3an^2]$. Now note that $3n^2\ge 2700$ and $a\ge1/2700$ to show that this is $\ge n^3+1$. However, for $a$ small enough, the LHS is still $n^3$.

It's tempting to conclude here. However, you may ask: is it possible that $a$ is so large, such that $[x^2]$ gets incremented as well, and somehow still resulting in the equality?

Intuitively, if $n=30$, then $[2an]\ge1$ implies $a\ge1/45$. But this implies $3an^2\ge60$. So the increment of $30\times1$ in the LHS fails to keep up with the increment of $60$ in the RHS. I'll let you figure it out for a general $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!